# How to get pull request comment body in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to get the first PR comment in a GitHub Actions workflow but the result is always empty.

This is what I have tried:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions: read-all

jobs:
  one:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
      - name: print body
        env:
            BODY: ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
        run: echo "$BODY"
      - name: Find Comment
        uses: peter-evans/find-comment@v2
        id: fc
        with:
            issue-number: 1
            body-includes: bla
      - run: |
          echo ${{ steps.fc.outputs.comment-id }}
          echo ${{ steps.fc.outputs.comment-body }}
          echo ${{ steps.fc.outputs.comment-author }}
          echo ${{ steps.fc.outputs.comment-created-at }}
```

and the call to this workflow is:

```bash
curl -L \                                                                                              
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer sometoken"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/actions/workflows/print-context.yml/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"somebranch"}'
```

Are there any other settings needed?

I am using `workflow_dispatch`. I think this is the problem. I am calling it using `curl` and the context seems to depend on the call. I have used a Python script to get the comment body instead.

As Azeem mentioned in the comments, this will not work without checkout first, I didn't realize this in the first place.

Comment: Add the `on` section of your workflow in your question.

Comment: You are printing `github` context as JSON, do you see that comment in there?

Comment: Update: I do have `on` section and it's set to `workflow_dispatch`. I think this is the problem. I am calling it using `curl` and the context seems to be depend on the call. I have used a python script to get the comment body instead.

Comment: Please add that in your question. It's unclear if that comment is for a PR or an input of the `workflow_dispatch` event. Thanks!

Comment: And, I just noticed that there's no checkout step in your workflow. This won't work without a checkout. Please add your complete workflow in your question along with your `curl` call too.

Comment: See https://github.com/peter-evans/find-comment. Its `repository` has the default value of `github.repository` which won't exist without checkout. It should be failing and properly log these things.